# How to kill all fragments created by a NavHostFragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, back-stack

I have 2 `navigation` files, and in my `Activity`, 2 `fragment`s. One of the navigations is always shown inside one of the fragments, but I show the other one only when I need it.

The way they're drawn is the always showing fragment is inside a relativeLayout, and the other fragment is inside the same relativeLayout with it's `visibility` set as `gone`. When I need the second navigation, I set the visibility to `visible` and when I don't need it, I set it to `gone` again.Visually this works well, but what I want to accomplish is that when I don't want the second navigation, I want to completely kill it and redraw it the next time I need it.

What I've done so far was to get a hold of the `NavHostFragment` used to start the navigation, and when I dont need it anymore, call `popBackStack()` on it's `navController`, but it doesn't work:

```
val navHost: NavHostFragment? = null

fun createSecondNav() {
   navHostLogin = NavHostFragment.create(R.navigation.navigation_second)

   theFragment.visibility = View.VISIBLE

   supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.theFragment, navHostLogin!!)
       .commit()
}

fun killSecondNav() {
   theFragment.visibility = View.GONE
   navHostLogin?.navController?.popBackStack() // returns false
   navHostLogin = null
}
```

So how can I completely kill the fragments created by the second `navHost`?

Answer (score 0):

`NavController` maintains it's own back-stack, independent form the `FragmentManager` back-stack.

And `popBackStack()` without arguments only pops that back-stack once:

> Attempts to pop the controller's back stack. Analogous to when the user presses the system Back button when the associated navigation host has focus.

While [`popBackStack(int destinationId, boolean inclusive)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#popBackStack(int,%20boolean)) reads:

> Attempts to pop the controller's back stack back to a specific destination.
>
> > - `destinationId` int: The topmost destination to retain
> > - `inclusive` boolean: Whether the given destination should also be popped.

So this should be:

```
navController.popBackStack(R.id.startDestination, true)
```

---

I'd wonder why even using two `NavController`, because one can set the graph at run-time with [`setGraph(NavGraph graph, Bundle startDestinationArgs)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#setGraph(androidx.navigation.NavGraph,%20android.os.Bundle)):

> Sets the navigation graph to the specified graph.
>   **Any current navigation graph data (including back stack) will be replaced**.

Comment: well the problem is that I don't have a `startDestination` to go to. I just want to completely kill and remove all the fragments created by the `NavHostFragment` that are defined in that `navigation` file since I don't need them anymore. I need one of the fragments in the background open, and at this point, it's just not feasible to integrate all the fragments inside one `navigation` file.